# RFC email regex pattern is shown as error in visual studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

I'm using the [exact email regex pattern](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) from the RFC :

```
 [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

However

When I paste it in vs :

```
var emailPattern = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/i;
```

it is shown with error : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkJJE.jpg

[image]

*Undetermined string constant*

How can I remove this error ?

Comment: I think you need to escape your `/` in your regexp if you decide to use the `/` as a delimiter so replace in the regexp each `/` by `\/`

Comment: @koopajah you mean at the edges ? ( I cant - this is the actual regex decleration.)

Comment: no I mean the other ones! Since you use the slash at the edges to say "my regexp start here, and ends there" you need to say "ok this `/` is not the end, it is part of the regexp". Not sure I'm clear (or right)

Comment: @koopajah Make it an answer.

Comment: yeah. Other solution on the net showes to create `new Regexp("...` but this is light weight solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to escape your `/` in your regexp if you decide to use the / as a delimiter so replace in the regexp each `/` occurrence by `\/`.

The thing is, as the first and last `/` are here to indicate where you regexp really starts and where it really ends, you need to escape `/` inside the regexp for the parser to understand where to stop.

This should work :

```
var emailPattern = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/i;
```

And as you pointed out in your comment, using the construct `new Regexp("...")` allows you to build your regexp without having to escape.

Both constructs are equivalent. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)